# Http Client hanging for some reason

Tags: java, http, netbeans, httpclient, wampserver

Working on a HTTP client program using Netbeans.

So far I have gotten to here in my HttpClient class:

```
public class MyHttpClient {

MyHttpRequest request;
String host;

public MyHttpResponse execute(MyHttpRequest request) throws IOException {

    //Creating the response object
    MyHttpResponse response = new MyHttpResponse();

    //Get web server host and port from request.
    String host = request.getHost();
    int port = request.getPort();

    //Check 1: HOST AND PORT NAME CORRECT!
    System.out.println("host: " + host + " port: " + String.valueOf(port));

    //Get resource path on web server from requests.
    String path = request.getPath();

    //Check 2: ENSURE PATH IS CORRECT!
    System.out.println("path: " + path);

    //Open connection to the web server
    Socket s = new Socket(host, port);

    //Get Socket input stream and wrap it in Buffered Reader so it can be read line by line.
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    //Get Socket output stream and wrap it in a DataOutputStream so it can be written to line by line.
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    //Get request method
    String method = request.getMethod();

    //Check 3: ENSURE REQUEST IS CORRECT GET/POST!
    System.out.println("Method: " + method);

    //GET REQUEST

    if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
        //Send request to server
        outToServer.writeChars("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.0");

        //HTTP RESPONSE
        System.out.println("WAITING FOR RESPONSE!");

        String line = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Line: " + line);


    }

    //Returning the response
    return response;

}
```

}

I have checked to ensure my request line is constructed correctly, as seen in the print statements throughout. However when I get to this line the program hangs:

```
System.out.println("WAITING FOR RESPONSE!");

        String line = inFromServer.readLine();
```

I have no idea why... My server is localhost WAMP. It is up and running correctly. I have the file I am requesting stored on the localhost. I can access it through browser.

Any ideas what might be going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CR or LF is one of your problems. You should be writing ASCII characters and may be a Host header.

```
outToServer.write(("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
outToServer.write("Host: myhost.com\r\n\r\n".getBytes("ASCII"));
outToServer.flush();
```